# How do I maintain spell check when copy and pasting into Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

Whenever I screenshot and paste into Word, spell check always turns off. How do I change this so that whenever I paste into Wrrd, spell check does not turn off. Note that I have changed default wrap text to top and bottom. Thank you.

Comment: Not reproducible on Word 2019. Try to [open Word in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72) to check for a problematic add-on.

Comment: Not reproducible in Word 2016 (365) either. Also try a Full Repair of Office to see it that fixes it. Also replace the Normal.dotm template to default.

Comment: Are you expecting Word to spell check your screenshot? That won't work. It doesn't spell check images.

Comment: Rather than paste a screenshot, select the text and paste that as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

One soluton: When pasting an image, screenshot, and the like, instead of hitting enter after the image and then typing your text, first insert a space (press the space bar), and then start typing (or hit enter). This should solve the problem. (I think you can also paste the image first, and then hit the spacebar before you start typing.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).